# Install Oracle Apex in Microsoft server 2016

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, windows-server

1. Oracle Database Express Edition (Oracle Database XE). Preferably latest version.
2. Oracle Application Express (APEX) 18.1 or greater. Preferably latest version.
3. Oracle WebLogic, Glassfish, TomCat, etc. as long as it supports ORDS
4. Oracle REST Data Services (ORDS) release 3.0.12 or later.

Is 1 and 2 installation same as windows? why do I need 3 and 4?

Comment: You deleted your other question, but that doesn't stop your API key from being visible on this site. Nor does it take it back from anyone that's already seen it, including me and the bots that scrape StackOverflow for this exact thing. You need to disable it and re-issue a new key.

Comment: Your API key is still valid, and furthermore has been immortalized on some random russian stackoverlfow clone: http://qaru.site/questions/16876388/geocoding-in-php-is-not-working-in-online-hosting

Comment: I have changed the key.

Answer (score 3):

XE latest version of Database isn't available for Windows yet, but will be soon. For now, you have an 11gR2 version of XE.

I'd wait a bit if you can for the 18c version of XE to drop for Windows.

Installation of XE or the database on Windows is via a GUI installer for both the server and creating a database and it's services. On NIX, you have YUM or RPM solutions, which are generally easier (personal opinion).

APEX installation happens in the database itself, process is the same regardless of your OS.

Tomcat or WLS aren't required, but are there to help manage ORDS (Java EE app). Most customers setup Apache with Tomcat for ORDS and APEX.

ORDS itself makes things inside the database available via HTTPS - one of those things is your APEX applications.

ORDS can also be ran as a standalone process, and this also gives you a built-in webserver (Jetty.)

Finally, if you're using ORDS, you can also build and deliver REST APIs for your database.

P.S. You could also use Docker to make things easier. [Joel Kallman shows how here](https://joelkallman.blogspot.com/2017/05/apex-and-ords-up-and-running-in2-steps.html).

Comment: Hello! Thanks for responding.
1. While installing Apex in windows os I normally put http port 8282, Will that be same in windows server?
2. So if I just install Oracle XE 11g and APEX 18.1 in the normal windows installation Procedure, I will be able to use them in windows server, ORDS is not mandatory?

Comment: the db has a built in listener using the XDB technology, but it's not recommended. for prod deployments i'd recommend ORDS (with or w/o apache/tomcat) and setup HTTPS, so you'd be on port 443

Comment: also, you want your web server probably on a different machine than your database

Comment: And if you're desperate for 18c XE (which I recommend because its got sooooo much more functionality that 11g XE), then you can run the linux port in a Virtualbox on your Win machine.  (Virtualbox is free)